# Correct way to persist embedded relationships in ember-data in a Ember-cli application

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am facing a situation in which I need to persist an embedded relationship into database. I am describing a similar situation in this question. It is an ember-cli project.

I have two models:

```
//app/model/post.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Post = DS.Model.extend({
    entry:          DS.attr('string'),
    comments:       DS.hasMany('comment')
});

export default Post;

//app/models/comment.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});

export default Comment;
```

1 Serializer:
    //app/serializers/post.js
    import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    comments: {
      embedded: 'always'
    }
  }
});
```

1 Route:

```
//app/routes/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post', 1);
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var newComment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {});
        newComment.set('text', 'xxxx comment');

        model.get('comments').pushObject(newComment);
        model.save().then(function(){
            console.log(model.toJSON());
            comments = model.get('comments');
            comments.forEach(function(comment){
                console.log("Comment: " + comment.get('text'));
                console.log("Comment id: " + comment.get('id'));
            });
       });
    }
});
```

So, the GET call in `model` hook the server returns:

```
// GET /posts/1
{
    "posts": {
        "id": "1",
        "entry": "This is first post",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "This is the first comment on first post"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "This is the second comment on first post"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When in the `setupController` hook, I add a new comment to the post and save it, its actually sending a `PUT` request with the following body:

```
// PUT /posts/1 -- Request
{
    "posts": {
        "id": "1",
        "entry": "This is first post",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "This is the first comment on first post"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "This is the second comment on first post"
            },
            {
                "post": "1",
                "text": "xxxx comment"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The server returns the following output:

```
// PUT /posts/1 -- Response
{
    "posts": {
        "id": "1",
        "entry": "This is first post",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "This is the first comment on first post"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "This is the second comment on first post"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "post": "1",
                "text": "xxxx comment"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But now in the console log I get the following output:

```
Comment: This is the first comment on first post
Comment id: 1
Comment: This is the second comment on first post
Comment id: 2
Comment: xxxx comment
Comment id: 3
Comment: xxxx comment
Comment id: null
```

Why is the new comment returned with `id` is added to the post's comments and is not replacing the comment?
Am I doing anything wrong or I need to add something else for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data would have no exact way of recognizing the difference between a record that user attempted to save and a record a different user attempted to save.

All it can safely know is that a new record with a new id came back (since there was no unique identifier on the record before, and you didn't specify to save that exact record).

In a non multi-user world, it could assume the new record should replace the existing record, but the Embedded Record stuff just isn't that smart yet.

#### 1. Delete the record after you save (cause you know it'll get duped, hacky)

```
var comments = model.get('comments');
comments.pushObject(newComment);
model.save().then(function(){
  comments.popObject(newComment);
  newComment.deleteRecord(); // not really necessary
  ...
});
```

#### 2. Save the record from the comment's point of view (cheapest and cleanest, might be a bit of additional server side logic for you)

```
newComment.save();
```

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k , this worked. In the actual scenario, the parent model will have many configurations which are nested and hence when the user saves the parent record the whole document has to be saved(With all the nested configurations). So, for me saving the comment(in this scenario) will not make sense.